# Null Space of a matrix and it's square

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck trying to solve the following problem from my linear algebra homework:

Show that if A $\in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$,  then dim$(N_{A^{2}}) \leq 2$ dim$(N_{A})$, i.e that dim$(N_{A^{2}})$ - dim($N_{A}) \leq $ dim$(N_{A})$.

So I know that if the matrix A is the zero matrix it holds trivially. What I was thinking was that $N_{A} \subseteq N_{A^{2}}$ so that dim$(N_{A}) \leq $ dim$(N_{A^{2}})$. And I was hoping to do a proof by contradiction; I get a contradiction in the case that dim$(N_{A}) = $ dim$(N_{A^{2}})$ but I wasn't sure about the other case when dim$(N_{A}) < $ dim$(N_{A^{2}})$.

Any help would be much appreciated, even if that means taking a different approach to the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Note that you can use the `\mbox` latex function to write, say straight "dim", for example, as `\mbox {dim}`.

Comment: @Sanath: Or just `\dim`.

Answer (score 1):

If you restrict $A$ to it's image then the kernel is just the kernel of $A$ intersected with the image.  So the dimension of the intersection must be less than or equal to the dimension of the kernel.

Comment: I think you mean that the **dimension** of the null space is the dimension of the kernel.

Comment: Seth, I'm not sure what you mean by "restrict A to it's image". Do you mean that $N_{A} \cap R_{A} \subseteq N_{A}$? How will this help here relating the null space of A and of $A^{2}$?

Comment: Sorry maybe this explanation wasn't clear enough.  I have to sleep now though maybe someone else can give a more clear explanation.